# How to mix Grammar (Rules) & Dictation (Free speech) with SpeechRecognizer in C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi, voice-recognition

I really like Microsofts latest speech recognition (and SpeechSynthesis) offerings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554855.aspx

http://estellasays.blogspot.com/2009/04/speech-recognition-in-cnet.html

However I feel like I'm somewhat limited when using grammars.

Don't get me wrong grammars are great for telling the speech recognition exactly what words / phrases to look out for, however what if I want it to recognise something i've not given it a heads up about? Or I want to parse a phrase which is half pre-determined command name and half random words?

For example..

**Scenario A** - I say "Google [Oil Spill]" and I want it to open Google with search results for the term in brackets which could be anything.

**Scenario B** - I say "Locate [Manchester]" and I want it to search for Manchester in Google Maps or anything else non pre-determined

I want it to know that 'Google' and 'Locate' are commands and what comes after it are parameters (and could be anything).

**Question : Does anyone know how to mix the use of pre-determined grammars (words the speech recognition should recognise) and words not in its pre-determined grammar?**

Code fragments..

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;

...
...

SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();
rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;

var c = new Choices();
c.Add("search");

var gb = new GrammarBuilder(c);
var g = new Grammar(gb);
rec.LoadGrammar(g);
rec.Enabled = true; 

...
...

void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Text == "search")
    {
        string query = "How can I get a word not defined in Grammar recognised and passed into here!";

        launchGoogle(query);
    }
}

...
...


private void launchGoogle(string term)
{
    Process.Start("IEXPLORE", "google.com?q=" + term);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this...
It specifies a list of known commands.. but also lets you use open dictation afterwards.
It expects there to be a command given before the open dictation.. but you could reverse this... and append th
However, by adding in a blank in the command type (" ") it will also let you get straight to the dictation part.

```
Choices commandtype = new Choices();
commandtype.Add("search");
commandtype.Add("print");
commandtype.Add("open");
commandtype.Add("locate");

SemanticResultKey srkComtype = new SemanticResultKey("comtype",commandtype.ToGrammarBuilder());

 GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
 gb.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
 gb.Append(srkComtype);
 gb.AppendDictation();

 Grammar gr = new Grammar(gb);
```

then on your recognizer just use the result text etc

```
private void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);

}
```

You can add more choice options, and SemanticResultKeys to the structure to make more complex patterns if you wish. Also a wildcard (e.g.  gb.AppendWildcard();  ).

Comment: I will try it again but the program kept crashing when calling gb.AppendDictation();

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices:

1. You can use the dictation node for free-text using [GrammarBuilder::AppendDictation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576565.aspx).  The problem is that since the recognizer doesn't have any context, the recognitions aren't the highest quality.
2. You can use a textbuffer node and provide a set of items using [GrammarBuilder::Append(String, SubsetMatchingMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576574.aspx).  This will give the recognizer enough context to get good quality recognitions without having to rebuild the entire grammar tree every time.

Comment: Cheers Eric. I will try these. Have you any examples of how to implement? as the msdn documentation for the System.Speech.Recognition is a bit sparse.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the native (C++) side.  I've opened a bug with MSDN about the missing descriptions.  In the meantime, the documentation for the Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder is apparently working, and most of the details work in both environments.  (Microsoft.Speech.Recognition is the managed interface to the Server SR & TTS engines.)

Comment: I'm going to try the sample here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd167810%28v=office.13%29.aspx later. Cheers

Comment: The speech recognition keeps crashing whenever I use .AppendDictation()! not good!

Comment: Can you send a backtrace?  You can contact me via my blog.