# Adding any text to Windows Phone's Voice Command Definition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, voice-recognition

I have a shopping list app and I want the user to be able to speek "Shopping list add milk" with the app launching and adding "milk" to the list of items to buy.

I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CreatingaVCDfile but it looks like you cannot use just any text when defining a voice command. I would like to define something like

```
<ListenFor> add {anyText} </ListenFor>
```

But if I understand it correctly, `{anyText}` must be a PhraseList defined in the VCD. So is there any way to to being able to speek a command followed by any text, like in my example?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046921/how-to-mix-grammar-rules-dictation-free-speech-with-speechrecognizer-in-c?lq=1